# How to automatically "like" Twitter tweets with JavaScript helper console code

Tags: javascript, twitter, automation, console

I am trying to search for a term in Twitter, and then "like" the tweets that come up, using JavaScript code in the console.

I tried making a class substitution into this working facebook code for auto-inviting users to like your page:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('a._42ft._4jy0._4jy3._517h');

for(var i=1; i<inputs.length;i++) {
inputs[i].click();
}
```

When I inspect the heart icon used by Twitter for liking a tweet, i see

```
<button class="ProfileTweet-actionButton js-actionButton js-actionFavorite" type="button">
```

so i tried

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('button.ProfileTweet-actionButton.js-actionButton.js-actionFavorite');

for(var i=1; i<inputs.length;i++) {
inputs[i].click();
}
```

in the console.

It is giving an undefined error.

Any ideas for how to change this code to work as intended?

Answer (score 1):

for unlike :

```
for (var j = 1; j < 1000; j++) {
  var input = document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="unlike"]');
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
   input[i].click();
   window.scrollBy(0, 600); 
}}
```

Comment: Im afraid it does not really answer the question, where it was asked for `like` not `unlike`

Comment: all you have to do is type `like` instead of `unlike` => `document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="like"]');`

Answer (score 1):

To determine the number of "likes,"  change the first line where  `j < 9`  to whatever number you're aiming for. Very helpful when following a hashtag or after searching for a particular term.

```
for(var j = 1; j < 9; j++) {
for (const d of document.querySelectorAll('div[data-testid="like"]')) {
    d.scrollIntoView(true);
    d.click()
  }}
```

If you are trying to 'unlike' instead of 'like' just change line 2:

`for (const d of document.querySelectorAll('div[data-testid="unlike"]')) {`

Answer (score 0):

The right code for the twitter feed hearts is:

```
javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('HeartAnimation');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) 
{ 
    inputs[i].click(); 
}
```

Comment: Hello, it seems like your code got cutoff in the middle. Consider updating your answer, and formating it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("div[aria-label=Like]");  
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {  
    x[i].click();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your browsers console

Windows

`ctrl`+`shift` + `j`

Mac

`cmd`+`shift` + `j`

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  // Find all elements with class "css-1dbjc4n r-xoduu5"
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.css-1dbjc4n.r-xoduu5');

  // Loop through each element and click on it
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].click();
  }
}, 5000);
```